# JS throws an error on response.data on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, axios

I encountered a problem where everything is properly working on pc, but on mobile phone, it is a different story. When the request is done on pc, it alerts the user on the screen that: "Name is required." and so on (I did not fill name or other properties in purpose). However, when this time I try it on mobile phone, it throws me an error that `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')` and gives reference to the line `const data = await err.response.data;`

There is a code snippet:

```
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Context-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };

      const res = await axios.post(
        USERS_PATH,
        {
          name,
          surname,
          email,
          password,
          repeatedPassword,
        },
        config
      );
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      const data = await err.response.data;
      userCtx.updateAlertMessage(Object.values(data).flat());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should crush regardless of the platform. To fix it, check if the response is null before accessing the data. You can do it using the `?` null checker.

Modified line:
`const data = await err.response?.data;`

Comment: Yea, I thought about it too. Unfortunately, the errors goes to the next line: ```userCtx.updateAlertMessage(Object.values(data).flat());```
It says: ```TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object```

Comment: then what you can do is check if its null and assign a default value to it (with keeping the ?). You can also use the || operator to assign a default value. @Mantofka